# Xtext. Can't add HyperlinkHelper

Tags: xtext

I try to customize HyperlinkHelper. So I have override HypertextDetector

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IRegion;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Region;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.IHyperlink;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.hyperlinking.DefaultHyperlinkDetector;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.hyperlinking.IHyperlinkHelper;

public class MyHyperlinkDetector extends DefaultHyperlinkDetector {
    private static final String PREFERENCES = ".hyper";

    @Override
    public IHyperlink[] detectHyperlinks(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion region, boolean canShowMultipleHyperlinks) {
        IDocument document = textViewer.getDocument();
        int offset = region.getOffset();

        // extract relevant characters
        IRegion lineRegion;
        String candidate;
        try {
            lineRegion = document.getLineInformationOfOffset(offset);
            candidate = document.get(lineRegion.getOffset(), lineRegion.getLength());
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            return null;
        }

        // look for keyword
        int index = candidate.indexOf(PREFERENCES);
        if (index != -1) {

            // detect region containing keyword
            IRegion targetRegion = new Region(lineRegion.getOffset() + index, PREFERENCES.length());
            if ((targetRegion.getOffset() <= offset)
                    && ((targetRegion.getOffset() + targetRegion.getLength()) > offset))
                // create link
                return new IHyperlink[] { new PreferencesHyperlink(targetRegion, candidate) };
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public IHyperlinkHelper getHelper() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new MyHyperlinkHelper();
    }
}
```

Hyperlink detector is worked, but MyHyperlinkHelper is never created. Even if I comment method detectHyperlinks.

My goal is to open file with name what I have click in my edited dsl grammar. That's why I need HyperlinkHelper. I.e. I need to check does my substring is correct file name.

How to solve it?

Regards,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 1):

dont override the method. simply use guice and call the method from the superclass in your impl

```
public Class<? extends IHyperlinkHelper> bindIHyperlinkHelper() {
    return DomainmodelHyperlinkHelper.class;
}
```

or in Xtend

```
def Class<? extends IHyperlinkHelper> bindIHyperlinkHelper() {
    return DomainmodelHyperlinkHelper;
}
```

Comment: May I ask you to give me details of using guice in the given context? What exactly I need to buind?

Comment: For what component?

Comment: Well, actually I woud like to ask: do I need to buind HyperlinkHelper, or also HyperlinkDetector?

Comment: Depends on what you actually did customize

Comment: Well, I woud like to do following: there are dsl-file contains links on the another DSL files. I woud like to check, does particular line contains the link. Underline it and by ctrl+click open the editor with given file.

Comment: As I said you need to bind the stuff you customized. Or you introducing real references by giving the model root as name it's file name and reference the model root